# Range of the sine function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

It is obvious from the definition of $f(x)=\sin(x)$ using the unit circle of radius $1$ that the range of that function is the set $[-1,1]$. But also there are approaches where the sine is defined using its Taylor series expansion:

$\sin(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {{(-1)^i}{x^{2i+1}}}{(2i+1)!}$

Now, what I would like of you to show me, how we can show that the range of the sine function is $[-1,1]$ if we define it by its Taylor series expansion?

Cheers!

Edit: I was thinking of this, we could somehow show by using the Taylor series expansion for sine and cosine that it holds that $(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2=1$. So to solve the question it should be sufficient to show that there exists some $x_1$ such that $\sin (x_1)=-1$ and some $x_2$ such that $\sin (x_2)=1$ and now the solution will follow form the fact that sine is continuous, so by the intermediate value theorem it would take any value between $[-1,1]$. But how to show the existence of such $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Even after showing what your edit suggests wouldn't be enough since that only would prove that the codomain of $\,\sin x\,$ is *contained* in $\,[-1,1]\,$ , but there still could be some real for which $\,|\sin x_0|>1\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio There couldn`t be such real because it could be shown from the series expansion of sine and cosine that $(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2=1$ and from that it follows non-existence of such a real.

Comment: But if we **already** know that the Trigonometric Pythagoras theorem applies when defining these guys by means of power series then we **already** know that $\,|\sin x|\le 1\,$ ...!

Comment: We know that $\,|\sin x|\le 1\,$ but it could be the case that $|\sin x|<1$, it is not obvious that we have $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $\sin (x_1)=-1$ and $\sin (x_2)=1$, am I missing something important here?

Comment: I thought *all the time* that you were asking to prove $\,|\sin x|\le 1\,$ solely from the power series definition, so how come now "we do know..." ?!

Comment: Oh, it is just that I didn`t express myself quite good, what I meant is that if we help ourselves with this question with  using also Taylor series definition for cosine and then showing that it holds $(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2=1$ we could conclude that $\,|\sin x|\le 1\,$ but that doesn`t show that it isn`t the case that $|\sin x|<1$, or in other words, that the strict inequality holds, do you understand me now?

Comment: Then do please change your question *completely* for "I want to show that there are $\,x_0\,,\,x_1\in\Bbb R\,$ s.t. $\,\sin x_0=-1\;,\;\sin x_1=-1\,$ using only the power series definition of sine...! Otherwise it is not merely that you didn't express yourself *quite good*: you asked something different altogether: just check it again!

Comment: @ DonAntonio You are completely right, maybe it would be better that I didn`t edit the question so that we see if anyone could show that the range is $[-1,1]$ using only the Taylor expansion formula for sine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulas $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ follow quite straightforwardly from the Taylor expansions for each function. Now, $\sin^2x +\cos^2x = \frac{e^{2ix}-2+e^{-2ix}}{-4}+\frac{e^{2ix}+2+e^{-2ix}}{4}=1$.

Now, $\cos(0)=1$ is immediate from the series, as are the relations $\sin '(x)=\cos x$ and $\cos' (x)=-\sin (x)$. So, $\sin (x)$ is increasing at $x=0$,  but $\sin (\pi 3/2)<0$ by direct evaluation of the series at $x=\pi 3/2$. So, $\sin (x)$ attains a maximum at some $y>0$, thus $\cos(y)=0$, and thus $\sin(y)=1$. Now, the formula $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ is immediate from the series expansion, and so $\sin (-y)=-1$.

This proof is along the lines you were asking for. Note also that the above does not really contain any complex analysis. The part involving $i$ can be replaced by a slightly more cumbersome expression. Basically, the $e^{ix}$ business is just a slick way to hide some combinatorics. You can unpack it if you like.

Comment: The first part is complex anaylis "light" and the OP already asked not to go there...

Comment: Also, Ittay, you wrote "So, $\sin (x)$ attains a maximum at some $y>0$, thus $\cos (y)=0$. How do you know that it is the case that at the maximum of sine $\cos (y)=0$. Correct me if I didn`t correct you in a good way?

Comment: @DonAntonio Am I right?

Comment: @Thus if $f$ attains a maximum at $y$ then $f'(y)=0$.

Comment: You are completely right about that! :-)

Comment: But still, I wonder how do you see that "$\sin (\pi 3/2)<0$ by direct evaluation of the series at $x=\pi 3/2$". Is it really obvious?

Comment: @Thus you evaluate the series using the standard remainder forms. Add up enough terms to get a negative partial sum that is accurate enough to guarantee the actual sum is negative. It's the most straightforward way that uses nothing but the series. It's not obvious, but not hard.

Comment: So, if i didn`t edit the question so that we can use the help by assuming that we also use the Taylor series definition of cosine but remained at the first idea that we show that the range of $\sin x$ is $[-1,1]$ by using only the power series definition for sine, then the question would be considerably more difficult?

Comment: yes and no. You can repeat the entire argument I gave without calling the other power series by names of familiar functions. It will be essentially the same solution, but more cumbersome, not more difficult. Of course, always when you try to do something with your hands deliberately tied behind your back, things are more difficult. And really, these three functions go together in a fundamental way. To separate them is unnatural.

Comment: I think that I understand what you are saying, someone could take the derivative of sine and call it wine, then (this is the way to avoid complex analysis) using the Cauchy product for the series show that $(sine)^2 + (wine)^2=1$ and the result follows from the arguments you gave in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: using the series for $\,e^z\;,\;\;z\in\Bbb C\,$ , prove that in fact

$$\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\Longrightarrow$$

$$|\sin x|=\frac{1}{2}|e^{ix}-e^{-ix}|\le\ldots$$

Comment: I should have mention that, but I would like to stay in the domain of real analysis. Can you think of some approach that doesn´t use complex analysis?

Comment: Of the top of my head, right now...not without the trigonometric circle and the usual definition

Comment: So, even though I wasn´t completely aware of it at the moment of asking the question, this is a difficult one, am I right?

Comment: Well, not necessarily, @Thus: it well may be that I'm missing some rather easy trick/fact...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not sure how what you propose actually solves the problem. You only get a $\le$, so you don't know that $\pm 1$ would be attained. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, @Ittai: you are not. I was addressing the original OP about showing the codomain is $\,[-1\,1]\,$ by first showing $\,|\sin x|\le 1\,$ , and then using the complex definition to pick up all the necessary details: the values in $\,\pi/2\;,\;-\pi/2\,$ , etc.